# How to accept clipboard data dropped onto a Racket canvas

Tags: racket

I am writing a UI app using Racket and would like to be able to drag-n-drop items, such as images, from other applications. Specifically, I want to drag an image from a web page in a browser (such as Chrome or FF) and drop it onto a `canvas%` in the app, receiving the raw image data as a result (the app will examine the PNG metadata before accepting the dropped image).

There is no functionality (that I can find) directly on the `canvas%` class, or super-classes, that relate to clipboard events.

I am familiar with clipboard d-n-d in other frameworks such as Swing and Win32.

It looks like the `clipboard-client%` class is what is required, but the Racket documentation makes it hard to connect the dots with respect to attaching it to one of the window classes.

Are there any good tutorials or sample code that I can refer to ?

---

Update: I took a look at the Racket source (OSX) for clipboard.rkt and it appears to only access the "general" pasteboard. OSX has a separate pasteboard for drag-n-drop operations.

So, it looks like d-n-d is not possible in Racket on OSX and I will have to use the Objective-C FFI to implement the required functionality and limit my users to those using Macs.

Closing this question.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, the Racket gui library only handles drag-and-drop of "files" through the `accept-drop-files` and `on-drop-file` methods of the `window<%>` interface, which `canvas%` implements. I'm not familiar with dnd protocols, but at least on Linux, images dragged from Firefox don't count as files, so they aren't accepted, whereas files dragged from nautilus are.

Here's the little program I used to test it:

```
#lang racket/gui

(define my-canvas%
  (class canvas%
    (define/override (on-drop-file file)
      (printf "got file: ~s\n" file)
      (super on-drop-file file))
    (super-new)))

(define f (new frame% (width 400) (height 400) (label "frame")))
(define c (new my-canvas% (parent f)))
(send c accept-drop-files #t)
(send f show #t)
```

I recommend asking on the [Racket mailing list](http://racket-lang.org/community.html).